# Get SPListItem from Linq to Sharepoint result

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, linq-to-sharepoint

I access a Sharepoint list with Linq-to-Sharepoint and iterate over the items in the result.

The items are (of course) just generated classes with only the properties from that list.

But I need some meta info to every item which I would have if I access it directly with `SPListItem`.

So how can I get a `SPListItem` object out of a Linq-to-Sharepoint result item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible but I don't delete the question in case anybody else is looking for it. Or someone finds a solution (which I will mark as answer then).